# Why does (Col <> value AND Col is null) not return any nulls?

Tags: t-sql, sql-null

I have an app where users can select various options off a page and the behind code builds a SQL query to return the relevant records.

In this case a user has selected:

- Division != '1'

There is also an automatic restriction, in that the Division of returned records has to be in the UserDivisions, which is a variable that looks like

```
Division IS NULL OR Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1')
```

So returned records have to be in one of the listed divisions, or have NULL as a value.

My code is currently processing these restrictions separately, so the final SQL looks like

```
Select top 1000 Division, WoNum, WoType 
From WorkOrder
Where (Division IS NULL OR Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1'))
AND (Division <> '1')
```

This query returns all the records with Division = '1.1' and '1.1.1', and it doesn't return any in Division '1', like it should, but it also doesn't return any records with Division = Null.

**How can I build this query to return NULLs as well, and why doesn't the above query return NULLs?**

Comment: `and (Division <> '1')` eliminates the nulls. because null can't be evaluated to <> '1'  it comes back "undefined" undfined isn't true and gets excluded.

Comment: @xQbert Why does it eliminate the nulls? Aren't nulls != '1' too?

Comment: Comparisons to NULLs always fail. That's why `Division IS NULL OR` was needed in the first condition. As it is, `Division <> '1'` will fail for any NULLs

Comment: @GreySage no, `NULL` means nothing. You can't compare nothing with something

Comment: Use: 
`WHERE ((Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1') AND (Division <> '1')) OR Division IS NULL)`

Comment: BTW the condition `Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1')` is more restrictive than `Division <> '1'`. You might as well remove it and use `Division IN ('1.1','1.1.1')`

Comment: *On the other hand* if you want to find *children* in a hierarchy, a) you should use a `hierarchyid` and b) looks like the query you wanted was `those children of "1" and any children of other root nodes`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos except 1 is in the first set but getting excluded by the division <> 1.  better would be `Division in ('1.1','1.1.1')`  but I'm gussing that as it's built dynamically its later so include first then exclude dynamic logic

Comment: @xQbert I suspect the real intention was to perform a hierarchical query - children of `1` and all other root nodes except `1`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Can you write up an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and (Division <> '1')` eliminates the nulls. This is because null can't be evaluated to <> '1'.  The RDBMS returns "undefined".  Undefined isn't true and gets excluded.

You could do this instead; but it seems odd since you want division 1 then exclude it.

`WHERE ((Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1') AND (Division <> '1')) OR Division IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

## When you compare a NULL to a value it always returns undefined

...which is not true and therefore evaluates as false. So `AND (Division <> '1')` will remove all NULLs from the return set.

Some ways to do the same query but include the nulls:

- `Where (Division IS NULL OR Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1'))
  AND (Division <> '1' OR Division IS NULL)`
- `WHERE ((Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1') AND (Division <> '1')) OR Division IS NULL)`
- `WHERE (ISNULL(Division,'') <> '1')
  AND (Division IS NULL OR Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1'))`
- `WHERE (COALESCE(Division,'') <> '1')
  AND (Division IS NULL OR Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1'))`

which is functionally equivalent to

- `WHERE (CASE WHEN Division IS NULL THEN '' ELSE Division END) <> '1'
  AND (Division IS NULL OR Division IN ('1','1.1','1.1.1'))`

Comment: Technically it's not false, nor is it true it's undefined.  but since the engine looks for true and it's not true then it gets ignored.